# Installing Pendant light which came with 3 clear wires and 1 copper/bare wire

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

Pendant light: 3 Clear Wire and 1 copper/ground wire

[image]

Ceiling: 1 Black, 1 white and 1 copper/ground wire

[image]

I do notice that in one of the three clear wires in the pendant, there is some number written, which could be neutral wire.

For another clear wire in the pendant I also notice 1 strand of wire is made of fabric. Can someone help me to fix it without using ohm meter?

Comment: Without using some sort of continuity tester, I don't think anyone can answer this. Did you try contacting the seller for instructions? The wire with the fabric strands might just be a strain relief cable not meant to be connected but that's just a guess and even if correct, You'll still have to identify the neutral and hot wires.

Comment: A battery and a flashlight bulb could help you figure it out. Are there 2 lamps in the fixture? this would be a home made continuity tester.

Comment: If you know the brand and model number of the new light, please post it. We probably can track down the manual/schematic and explain it to you.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I think it's [this lamp](http://www.lampsplus.com/products/possini-euro-satin-nickel-and-glass-mini-pendant-chandelier__r0762.html) based on the part number that appears in the photo, but I couldn't find a manual.

Comment: If so, since that's a simple one-bulb fixture,  the third "wire" is very likely to be a strain relief - not an electrical wire.  Buzz out the wires to determine which two reach the socket, and use the **other** one to support the weight.

Answer (score 1):

A pendant light needs 4 wires:

- Hot
- Neutral
- Ground for the dangling lamp
- Ground for the box cover

Two of them go to metal contact points in the bulb socket. If one of them is easier to touch than the other, that should be neutral.

Honestly, I'd say if the accompanying documentation or online docs do not tell how to hook it up, then it goes back to the store/into the trash.  I would question the UL or CE listing, as I doubt they'd list a fixture with no clear way to hook it up.  I can only imagine they expect a qualified electrician to beep it out.  Well, digital voltmeters are $10 at Sears if cost is a factor - for a world-class one, Fluke.